# How to return data from temporary activity opened in a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

Basically I have a MainActivity which contains 3 different fragments, and within one of those fragments I can click a button that opens a new activity with a simple RadioGroup choice, and whenever I click on one of the options, it automatically closes the activity. Now, my problem is transfering that selected data to the fragment, so I can update it depending on which RadioButton I chose.

The closest I have come to a solution for this is startActivityForResult, but it seems that is no longer working...

Comment: `but it seems that is no longer working` it definitely does still work, there's just a newer way of doing it. can you please include code in your question to show what you've tried and what you're struggling with

Answer (score 1):

From official [guide doc](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result):

In your fragment, create & register a launcher

```
private val launcher = registerForActivityResult(
    ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()
) { result: ActivityResult ->
    handleResult(result)
}
```

Create a method to handle `ActivityResult`:

```
fun handleResult(result: ActivityResult) {

    // Handle the returned result as you do in onActivityResult()
    // Use result.resultCode to determine OK or Cancelled result

    if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        val resultIntent = result.data
        // Use returned Intent
    }
}
```

Launch the `OtherActivity` for result like this:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    // ...

    val selectButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.select_button)

    selectButton.setOnClickListener {
        // Launch activity from whom you want the result
        val intent = Intent(requireContext(), OtherActivity::class.java)
        launcher.launch(intent)
    }
}
```

In the `OtherActivity`, when you're ready to send back result, create  an intent and put the data in it.

```
val intent = Intent()
intent.putExtra("YOUR_KEY", YOUR_DATA_HERE)
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent)
finish()
```

After this, you will get result in `handleResult()` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences) to save the state of the radio buttons, or you can create a [callback function](https://medium.com/@Xiryl/handle-activity-fragment-backpress-callback-in-android-3f68f3920b24) that triggers the main activity when you dispose the fragment and pass as parameter the state of the radio buttons.

Comment: SharedPreferences should be left as the latest thing to do for this kind of activity because it involves a physical file and the need to clean it after "all is done" and/or when things goes in error, and Callbacks are useful when the Activity is the same, otherwise it could create memory leaks due to previous Activity (the one in which the callback exists) persistance. "Activity.startActivityForResult()" is just it is needed. PS: the author didn't excluded opened Activities are INSIDE his App, so your solutions could not be use in this case.